# Problema con Faker en Laravel

Tags: laravel, imagen, faker

Estoy usando Laravel 9. Tengo un factory con lo siguiente:

```
$imagen = $this->faker->image('public/storage/posts', 640, 480, null, false);
```

El directorio de destino existe, es accesible y tiene los permisos correctos.
Cuando intento ejecutar el factory desde el seeder, veo en el directorio que los archivos de imágenes se van creando y borrando inmediatamente. Al final de la ejecución, en el directorio no queda ninguna imagen.
He encontrado comentarios de que es un fallo de la clase Faker, pero nadie da la solución. Algunos dicen que les funciona, pero a otros no nos funciona.
En algunos sitios de Internet dicen que en el archivo `vendor/fakerphp/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Image.php` hay que buscar la línea:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
```

y añadir debajo:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Sin embargo, eso no resuelve el problema. Aparte de que andar modificando algo en la carpeta vendor de Laravel no parece la mejor idea.

Como podemos resolver ese problema de la clase Faker?

Comment: hola tengo este mismo problema, si por casualidad ya lo resolvistes me puedes ayudar... porque no consigo la solución por ningún lado

Comment: me sirvio lo del amigo Alejandro RD
BASE_URL de "..via.placeholder..." a "https://placehold.jp/" o a otro proveedor de imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia `BASE_URL` de "..via.placeholder..." a "https://placehold.jp/" o a otro proveedor de imágenes.

Esto funcionó para mí.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar este problema puedes utilizar un servicio de generador de imágenes online y almacenar en la base de datos el enlace.

Con lo que el seeder te quedaría asi

```
$imagen = 'https://api.lorem.space/image/face?w=600&h=600&key=' . Str::random(64)
```

El uso del `Str::random` es para que cuando imprimas varios elementos con esa imagen no te salgan imágenes duplicadas por lo que deberás importarlo al seeder.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

Hay bastante cantidad de imágenes y puedes especificar el tamaño que necesites para tu aplicación.

Puedes mirar la documentación aquí https://lorem.space